# what is the diffference between adding a return keyword during recursive function call and not adding return keyword?

Tags: c

```
int main ()
{ 
    static int i = 5;

    if (--i)
    {
        return main();
    }
    printf("%d", i); 
    return 0;
}
```

**output: 0**

```
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;

    if (--i)
    {
        main();
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

**output: 0 0 0 0 0**

```
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;

    if (--i)
    {
        main();
        printf("%d", i); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output: 0 0 0 0**

**why does return keyword cause this behaviour ?**
and why does snippet 3 produce the a different ouput ? 
Please explain in detail.

Comment: Can you show more of the program?

Comment: The `return` statement exits the function. If you don't have `return`, the function continues and executes the `printf()`.

Comment: these are 2 separate codes. both being exceuted in main() @jamieguinan

Comment: Unless there is some more code the first should produce no output and the second only a single 0. Please show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can reprdouce this output. Also, I think calling `main` from user code causes undefined behaviour (not sure though).

Comment: @Barmar could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @churill It's undefined in C++, allowed in C.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. It will show what happens.

Comment: `return main();` that's Undefined Behaviour. You are not allowed to call `main` yourself in C++. As a result, the entire program is invalid.

Comment: `main`: _"It cannot be used anywhere in the program...in particular, it cannot be called recursively"_. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: @Barmar have a look at code snippet 3

Comment: Instead of adding new cases you might run the code in a debugger and single step through it. Then you can clearly see what happens. Thats far better than getting things explained.

Comment: You ask why code 3 is different but you state same output as code 2.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `return` and non-`return` in a *non-recursive* function-call?

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag since calling `main()` is illegal in that language. However, there's nothing in the gist of the question that's specific to `main()`.

Comment: @DuaneRoyedDsilva I ran snippet 3, it only printed `0 0 0 0`, not `0 0 0 0 0`.

Comment: right. ive edited the question @Barmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In the version with `return`**, when the program starts `i` is initialized to `5`. It decrements `i` to `4`. This is non-zero, so the `if` block is entered.

It executes `return main()`. This calls `main` recursively, and when that returns, we exit the program (never executing the `printf()` call).

In the recursive call to `main()`, we decrement `i` to `3`. This is also non-zero, so the `if` block is entered.

It executes `return main()`. This calls `main` recursively, and when that returns, we return from this call, again not executing the `printf()` call.

The same thing happens when `i` is decremented to `2` and `1`, so I won't describe them.

Finally, we enter `main()` when `i` is `1`. We decrement it to `0`. This is `0`, so the `if` block is *not* entered. We continue with the rest of the function and execute `printf("%d", i);`, which prints `0`. Then the function returns.

Each of the previous recursive calls then return as well, so nothing else is printed.

**In the version without `return`**, everything is the same except the functions *don't* return immediately after the recursive calls return. They continue to the `printf()` statement. But these all happen after all the recursive calls have happened, so `i == 0` when each of them calls `printf()`, and you get 5 0's.

In the third version, the `printf()` call is inside the `if` block. It's similar to the second version, but it only prints `0` in the cases where `--i != 0`. So it prints `0` after each recursive call, but not inside the final call, because that one skips over the `if` block. So it prints `0` one less time than the second version.

Comment: And then there's the detail of calling `main` being UB.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Do you have a pointer into the standard? I don't see any problem with calling `main()` recursively, it's a normal function, just having that predefined name.

Comment: @thebusybee references: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function , https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main "... The function main shall not be used within a program ..."

Comment: @JesperJuhl Calling the `main` is legal in C.

Comment: @LxerLx Yes, it is legal in *C*. But not in C++. They are different languages and have different rules. What's your point?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've removed the C++ tag to avoid this issue. But the nature of the recursion is not really specific to main.

Comment: @Barmar Of course the recursion issue has nothing to do with `main`. But `main` *is* special - in both C and C++, but in this case *especially* in C++ since there calling `main` is not allowed. And the question *was* tagged C++, so I thought it reasonable to point it out.